# How can I combine the Find-commands?

Tags: find

*The question emerged my original question [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895501/union-intersection-and-exclude-with-the-find-command)*

I try to find the common elements between the outputs of the two find-commands with a find-command. How can I get the command working?

```
find `find ~/bin/FilesDvorak/.* -maxdepth 0` -and `find ~/.PAST_RC_files/.*`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would something like this work instead, rather than reinvent the wheel?

```
diff -qrs ~/bin/FilesDvorak/ ~/.PAST_RC_files/ | grep -P "are identical|differ"
```

You can play around with the grep to get the files present only in one of the dirs, etc.

diff

- -q  --brief Output only whether files differ.
- -r  --recursive Recursively compare any subdirectories found.
- -s  --report-identical-files Report when two files are the same.

grep

- -P: Perl style regex. You can probably do away just fine without it though, I usually add it automatically.

Comment: The option -P for grep seems to be only for Ubuntu. What is its purpose? I want to find a similar command for Mac too.

Comment: The options -q, -r and -s seem to be too Ubuntu-only. Could you explain their purpose? I want to convert the command for Mac too.

Comment: There's nothing that's Ubuntu only - diff is FSF and grep is GNU - they're available on all flavors of Linux and I don't see why they shouldn't be available on Macs.

Comment: Updated the solution with options explanation. In general, you can 'man CMD' to get its manual and explanation of all options or just look it up online.